# Number of customers in a given month if new customers leave after x number of months

Tags: excel-formula, period

How do I calculate total customers in a month as new customers join and old customers leave based on customer retention input.

Example:

Number of months customer stays: **3** (could be anywhere between 1-10; this input should drive row 2 ? below) customer leaves after this period

```
        Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  Jan'19   
New      0    2    3    2    2    3    5    5    5    3    3    1     0
Leaving  ?    ?    ?    ?    ?    ?    ?    ?    ?    ?    ?    ?     ?
Total   (1-?) x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x     x
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Jan` is in E1, that B2, C2 and D2 are empty, and no leavers or joiners prior to `Jan`:

in E3: `=SUM(B2:D2)`
in E4: `=SUM(C2:E2)`

copy both across to the right to suit.